# DRAKE_RESOURCE_ROOT is unset in Drake Docker

Tags: drake

I get the error:

```
because no resource roots of any kind could be found: DRAKE_RESOURCE_ROOT is unset, a bazel::tools::cpp::runfiles::Runfiles could not be created, and there is no Drake CMake install marker.Aborted (core dumped)
```

The fix is as follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add DRAKE_RESOURCE_ROOT to the bashrc file permanently.

`echo "export DRAKE_RESOURCE_ROOT=/" >> ~/.bashrc`

Remember to commit the container to have the change persistent.

`docker commit <container id> <container tag>` on a different terminal that is not running docker.

Comment: Can I ask which Dockerfile you're building this off of? Ideally, if Drake was setup correctly, it shouldn't need `DRAKE_RESOURCE_ROOT` at all, and should just rely on resource paths relative to the shared library.

Comment: I installed this Dockerfile: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/master/setup/ubuntu/docker/bionic/Dockerfile.nvidia-cuda-9.1-devel-ubuntu18.04